# Unable to change state property when clicking on child - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wanting to change the colour of text when I click on it by triggering a function in a child element, such that it affects the state of the parent - As a particular parent state property determines whether the text is one colour or another.

I know that the function fired in the child DOES feed back up to the parent, as I can get the parent to console.log properly. However, I can't seem to get it to change the state property.

*PS. I would like to use a "(prevState) =>" if this is applicable*

**Parent**

```
const tasks = [
  { name: 'task1', isComplete: false },
  { name: 'task2', isComplete: true },
  { name: 'task3', isComplete: false },
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tasks
    }
  }
  ...
  toggleTask(taskToToggle) {
    const foundTask = tasks.find(task => task.name === taskToToggle.name)

    foundTask.isComplete !== foundTask.isComplete;

    this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks })
  }
  ...
```

**Child**

```
return (
      <div key={name} style={taskStyle} onClick={this.handleToggleComplete.bind(this)}>
        {name}
      </div>

    )

handleToggleComplete() {
    const taskToToggle = this.props;
    this.props.toggleTask(taskToToggle);
  }
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `foundTask.isComplete !== foundTask.isComplete;`

Comment: Also, this `this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks })` doesn't update anything.

Comment: @Chris You have a way of making me see my own stupidity! You were correct in thinking !== was a typo - it should have been = !found...

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the same array and task object.

So that current state `tasks` is the same array as next state `tasks` containing the same objects.

You need to return another array for example using `Array.prototype.map`

```
 toggleTask(taskToToggle) {
    this.setState(({tasks}) => ({
      tasks: tasks.map(task => 
        task.name === taskToToggle.name ? {...task, isComplete: !task.isComplete} : task)
    }))
  }
```

Comment: This is a valid answer but I would honestly split it up a bit and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

in your child onClick pass the this.props.toggleTask and bind the name the task directly to it like :

```
onClick={this.props.toggleTask.bind(name)}
```

And in your Parent in the function dont use taskToToggle.name but just "name" :

```
const foundTask = tasks.find(task => task.name === name)
```

Or you can just change completly the function to make it easier like :

```
toggleTask(name){
  const updated = tasks.map(task => {
    if(task.name === name){
       task.isComplete = !task.isComplete
    }
   return task
  })
this.setState({tasks: updated})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to calculate the final state before assigning the state

change your

```
this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks }) //doesn't change anything
```

to

```
let finalState = Object.assign({}, ...this.state.tasks, foundTask)
this.setState({ tasks: finalState }) //new object gets assigned to state
```

Answer (score -1):

@Chris was correct in pointing out my n00bish error.

```
foundTask.isComplete !== foundTask.isComplete
```

Should have been

```
foundTask.isComplete = !foundTask.isComplete
```

This now works.

Comment: This is not the only problem with your code. You are reusing the same object and the same array. Referentially you are not changing anything.

Comment: This might work, but it shouldn't. If it works, it probably means that `foundTask` is a direct reference to an item inside `this.state.tasks` and by doing the above you are mutating the state directly! You need to make a copy of `state.tasks`, mutate the related item of the copy and then replace the original with the copy.

Comment: I get what you mean. Would this be done with something like using "prevstate => {...}"?